# Transform vertices on the CPU does not result in normalized coordinates

Tags: c++, directx

I have a working graphics pipeline with perspective projection. i wanted to get the transformed vertices on the CPU, now the only way to achieve that was to multiply the vector with my transformation matrices using `DirectX::XMVector4Transform`. I expected the resulting vectors to be normalized between -1 to 1 while all the vertices are inside the screen. But most of the vectors are more than 1 or less than -1. Using the same transformation matrices I transform the vertices in the gpu and it works perfectly. Using the same matrices i expect the vectors to be between -1 and 1 as long as the vertices are being rendered  on the screen (i.e they lie between -1 to 1).

I am sceptical about the `XMVector4Transform()` function. I don't expect `XMVector4Tranform` to normalize the verts, but isn't the projection matrix supposed to?? I am generating the perspective projection matrix with the DX function.

```cpp
projectedVectors[i].verts[j] = XMVector4Transform(XMVector4Transform(XMVector4Transform(v1, mWorld), *mView), *mProj);
```

I expect the resulting vectors to be normalized (i.e between -1 and 1) when the models is inside the screen. and i am sure about the matrices, i am using those to render stuff and that works perfectly fine. the verts are of the 3d model being rendered and i am watching the values when the 3d model is inside the screen area.

Comment: Please, note that `XMVector4Transform()` handles homogeneous coordinates i.e. 4 component vectors. Points in 3 space are assigned with w = 1 (vectors like e.g. normals with w = 0.) I recently noticed (in OpenGL) that perspective projection transformation changes the w component of the transformed vertices as well. You have to divide x, y, z by w if you expect them in range [-1, 1]. (If this is what you mean with "normalized" then the short answer is: Yes.)

Comment: Further reading: [Wikipedia: Homogeneous Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics_and_computer_vision) and [Song Ho Ahn: OpenGL Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html). It's surely not different in DirectX - the math is API agnostic. ;-)

Comment: Scheff's answer is accurate, dividing by W will be required to bring them into your expected range.   Also, for performance reasons, I would multiply out your matrices before executing XMVector4Transform.

Comment: but what am i supposed to put in my W component. after looking into it on the internet i found that the W component is set to z which then divides all the other components of the vector (as you mentioned), but the problem is that even if i do so (set the W to Z), i still doesn't work.......

Comment: Neither does it work when i set the w to 1

Comment: the results change though as i change the w component. i read that i have to use XMVector4Normalize() or something like that to get the values normalized...